# WPF tab from TabItem to TabItem within Tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, tabitem

Any idea how to, with no code behind, within a WPF TabControl, tab from the last control on a given TabItem (maybe a textbox) to the first control on the next TabItem?

Comment: With no code behind? why impose such rule? Too much MVVM?

Comment: It's a legit question. Suppose I wanted to do this for each of a dozen screens -- I would rather reuse an attached behavior than have codebehind in each screen.

Comment: I agree with the ChrisWue answer.  If you need to implement this ability in each of a number of instances, Derive and Conquer!

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd either need to derive from `TabControl` and add a handler to the `PreviewKeyDown` or `PreviewKeyUp` event and then do the logic in there or maybe you can get away with an `AttachedProperty` which you can set to true on the `TabControl` doing essentially the same.

If by "no code behind" you mean "xaml only and I don't want to write any code whatsoever" then I don't think it's possible.